# What's it mean when a variable sits outside brackets?

Tags: javascript

In Javascript what does it mean when you see a variable adjacent to brackets, something like this:

```
var1(var2)
```

How do they interact with each other?

Comment: It's a function call.  var2 is being passed to the var1 function (assuming it was declared as a function).  If you want to learn more about javascript, there are plenty of tutorials online that will go over the syntax.  I've heard good things about this one in particular: http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript.

Answer (score 1):

It means `var1` is a function that is being called with `var2` as an argument. For example:

```
var func = function(foo) {
  console.log(foo)
}

var arg = "Hello World!"

func(arg)  // prints "Hello World" in console
```

Answer (score 0):

That would be a plain old [function call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions).

Answer (score 0):

`var1(...)` would be interpreted as a *function call*. `var1` would be expected to resolve to a function. `var2` would also be resolved (before `var1` actually) and passed as *argument*.